# how to error check mysql update statment using php?

Tags: php, mysql

i am updating mysql row using the following code. could any one tell me how i can error check the update query and only print **Success** if the update query was successful without any error? and print **failed** if update query was not successful!

```
<?
    $IdVar = $_POST['rowId'];
    $DataVar = $_POST['NewData'];



    $server   = "localhost"; // MySQL hostname
    $username = "xxxxxx"; // MySQL username
    $password = "xxxxxx"; // MySQL password
    $dbname   = "test"; // MySQL db name

    $db = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
          mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());


      $result = mysql_query("update testDb SET username ='$DataVar' WHERE ID = '$IdVar'");
     if (!$result) {
                 die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                }

    echo "Success";

    ?>
```

Comment: where are you stucked????any error messages???

Comment: Define 'not successful'. Are you looking for errors, or just that the update query didn't find anything to update?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for mysql_affected_rows(), see: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are deprecated. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for details. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: BTW, you're vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent this.

Comment: thanks all for reply. i just want to echo success if row is updated but not sure if i placed the echo "Success"; in the right place!

Comment: No, you shouldn't "just want to echo success", you should really learn a few things about database security or your site will be hacked one day!

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysql_affected_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to count the number of affected rows. If it returns 0, no row was updated.

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_affected_rows](https://www.php.net/mysql_affected_rows) count the number of affected rows on success, and -1 if the last query failed.

```
echo ( mysql_affected_rows() > 0 ) ? "Success update" : "No rows update";
```

Answer (score 0):

**mysql functions are deprecated, so you may want to use mysqli_ functions.**

Using the deprecated mysql functions, one can use [mysql_errno](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php) to check if an error occurred.

```
$result = mysql_query("update testDb SET username ='$DataVar' WHERE ID = '$IdVar'");

if(mysql_errno($db)!=0) echo "Something went wrong";
```

I would not check mysql_affected_rows() as suggested by the other answers, because `mysql_affected_rows()=0` only implies that no row was updated, but it does not mean that an error occurred.

For example, if you have username="Rolf" with id=3, then if you execute

```
$result = mysql_query("update testDb SET username ='Rolf' WHERE ID = '3'")
```

no rows are affected, even though there was no error during the update.